# C# / How to get text in text box when i click button

Tags: c#

I want to close the program when I enter "close" in the text box and click button.

When I click button, get text in text box. And if the text is "close", close the program.

how to do it?

ps. I am trying it using winform

Comment: winform application or wpf?

Comment: Writing code I suppose. Please read [ask]

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

if its WPF:

```
if(txtYourTextBox.Text.ToUpper().Equals("CLOSE"))
{
   Application.Current.ShutDown();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
txtYourTextBox.Text
```

to get your typed text as string

then use:

```
if(txtYourText.Text== "close")
{
    Application.Exit();
}
```

to close your application